# Windows Server 2012 File Security Warning

Tags: group-policy, windows, windows-server-2012

I've mapped my domain users to a remote share, and I'm trying to get rid of the security warning that appears whenever a file is run from the remote share.

I've tried adding the FQDN to the intranet list with no prevail and I'm starting to go crazy. I've also turned off IE Enhanced Security Configuration for both Admins and Users.

The group policies are being applied, and I can see the FQDN in the intranet list in internet options.

## Relevant group policy:

[image: GP sniplet]

## Relevant security warning:

[image: Warning dialog]

Comment: "a file is run" --- binary executable, "managed" (CLR-based) executable, data file opened via a file type association (which your description makes it look like, but want to avoid misunderstandings)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I just wasn't waiting long enough for the relevant GPO settings to propagate.